# Hi I am trying to use the same collection name in my Procedure while declaring the cursor

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have defined two cursors in my procedure and trying to give the same collection name.

```
Error: PLS-00305: previous use of 'ty_cur' conflicts with this use

Cursor cur_1
IS Select ABC from table tab_1;
TYPE ty_cur TABLE OF cur_1 %ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
abc_cur ty_cur;

Cursor cur_2 IS
Select DEF from table tab_2;
TYPE ty_cur TABLE OF cur_2 %ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
abc_cur ty_cur;

Error: PLS-00305: previous use of 'TY_cur' conflicts with this use
```

I have also tried using NESTED TABLE for Cur_2 but the error remained same.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Why do you want to give same name by the way. Cursor overloading is possible but the input to the cursor must differ.

Comment: Hi, Its business requirement. I have to use it in that way.

Comment: No it isn't. The business cannot tell you to give the same name to two variables in your code, which is in any case impossible. Probably there is an actual requirement to achieve some end result.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple objects with the same name in the same scope. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/plsus.htm):

> **PLS-00305:** previous use of 'string' (at line string) conflicts with this use
>
> **Cause:** While looking for prior declarations of a cursor, procedure, function, or package, the compiler found another object with the same name in the same scope. Or, the headers of subprogram in a package specification and body do not match word for word.
>
> **Action:** Check the spelling of the cursor, procedure, function, or package name. Also check the names of all constants, variables, parameters, and exceptions declared in the same scope. Then, remove or rename the object with the duplicate name. Or, change the headers of the packaged subprogram so that they match word for word.